# What is the paramstr equivalent in Delphi Prism

Tags: delphi, delphi-prism, oxygene

Is there a simple statement that can give a result similar to paramstr() in Delphi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delphi Prism (.Net) does not include the [**ParamStr**](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=ParamStr) function, but can be easily implemented using the [**GetCommandLineArgs**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) method, [here](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2009/10/02/using-paramstr-in-delphi-prism/) is an example :

```
class method TMyClass.ParamStr(Index: Integer): String;
var
  MyAssembly: System.Reflection.Assembly;
  Params    : array of string;
begin
  if Index = 0 then
  begin
    MyAssembly:= System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly;
    if Assigned(MyAssembly) then
      Result := MyAssembly.Location
    else
      Result := System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess.MainModule.FileName;
  end
  else
  begin
    Params := System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs;
    if Index > Length(Params) - 1 then
      Result := ''
    else
      Result := Params[Index];
  end;
end;
```

Also you can see the [ShineOn](http://code.remobjects.com/p/shineon/) project that includes an implementation of the function [ParamStr](http://code.remobjects.com/p/shineon/source/tree/HEAD/trunk/Source/ShineOn.RTL/System.pas).